# titanium cloudpush notification hiding

Tags: notifications, titanium, acs

There is any option to hide the tray notifications when my app is in foreground ? and showing notifications when it close or in background ?
I tried to use :

showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused=false;
showTrayNotification=true;

but with no success... 
code example will be very useful.

thanx for you helps...